# How can I set focus on nearest input field when I click on table row. Something like <label> without text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with two columns and many rows. On the left side I will have once text, once nothing. On the right side I will have some input's or textarea's fields.

How can I set focus on input field when I click on left side on table row?
`<label>` working fine but only on text not on TR.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: create jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the label to fill the cell.

```css
td label {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="a">foo</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="a">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="b">barnj fklj kl</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="b">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="c">lorum ipsum</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="c">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="d">*fdhj*fdhj*</label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution is fine for me. Thanks ! Have You solution in jQuery ? 

$('tr').click(function() {
 $(this).next("input").focus(); 
});
Somethink like this code?

Comment: No. Using JavaScript for this is a terrible idea. My solution uses plain CSS.

Comment: Thanks this is great for me :)